# R-LWE instantiation with non-power of 2 polynomial

Tags: key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, lwe

In almost all RLWE papers, the polynomials are chosen from a ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial of the form $f(x)=x^{2^n}+1$. That leaves us the choice of polynomials like $x^{256}+1$, $x^{512}+1$ or $x^{1024}+1$ etc. Apart from irreducibility, I understand that using this polynomial has few other advantages like fast polynomial multiplication. One disadvantage of this is that it makes the sizes of keys or ciphertexts or signatures bigger. Just for example in the [NewHope](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1092.pdf) key-exchange scheme, their proposed parameter uses a polynomial of degree $1024$ which provides much more than $128$ bit security, whereas the less secure version (JARJAR) uses a polynomial of degree $512$ but provides security less than $128$ bits. Evidently, the former version sends much more data over the wire than the latter one.  But, what if I want to use a polynomial of degree that is between the above two, for example, $768$, it will provide sufficient security and will use a lesser amount of data.

Now my questions are

1. Can I use cyclotomic polynomial $\phi_{3*768}= x^{768} - x^{384} + 1$ as a modulus?
2. If yes, does the error distribution change? By what degree? (I understand there are some issues described in this paper [(How (Not) to Instantiate Ring-LWE)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/351.pdf) but it is little difficult for me)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: From what I know so far, [It's indeed been used](http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:935425/FULLTEXT01.pdf). The error distribution change for signatures had been described in the paper I've linked, and as for KEMs, I suppose non-power-of-two polynomials may cause error propagation to be greater, which makes reconciliation more difficult.

Comment: @DannyNiu Thanks, I did not know that. I will look into it.

Comment: @DannyNiu I did not see a discussion on error distribution in your referenced paper. Can you please mention the section?

Comment: I thought change in standard deviation might count as error distribution change. The paper mentioned how to derive parameters for the BLISS scheme. Discrete Gaussian is very much preferred in signature schemes so I don't think we need to change the "shape".

Comment: @DannyNiu Ok, I get it. Change in standard deviation is fine, as long as it is Gaussian. Now, suppose we have a reconciliation scheme that can alleviate the problem of error propagation. Is it then possible to change the polynomial (of course we have to change multiplication algorithm too.)

Comment: Gaussian is only needed in signature schemes, because we don't want to leak information on secret key. For KEMs, any distribution with good entropy-to-variance ratio would do, so NewHope used binomial distribution.

Comment: @Rick It's worth stating that if your goal is post-quantum security, you may want to consider schemes such as NTRU Prime.  I say this because if your use of a cyclotomic polynomial introduces any periodicity, it may not be pq-secure.  Also worth mentioning, Lyubashevsky stated at PQCrypto '17 that they are moving away from Gaussians due to weaknesses introduced by this component.

Comment: @floorcat Thank you. That's a very good information regarding the "introduction of cyclotomic polynomials". Can you please elaborate more? Or, perhaps help me with some material. Which cyclotomic polynomials may introduce periodicity?

Comment: @floorcat, for example, the polynomials mentioned in the document cited by DannyNiu $\phi_{3*648}=x^{648} - x^{324} + 1$ or $\phi_{3*768}=x^{768} - x^{384} + 1$, do they introduce periodicity?

Comment: @Rick That's not a question I can answer in a comment, but maybe someone else can chime in.  It looks like the second polynomial you listed is from your question, and fine-tuning the parameters of LWE has been the  main challenge of doing LWE correctly for some time.

Comment: @floorcat yes, it is. I took it from the article.

Answer (score 1):

On the IACR eprint archive there is a paper entitled ["*Even More Practical Key Exchanges for the Internet using Lattice Cryptography*"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1120.pdf) by Singh and Chopra that discusses using other cyclotomic fields which provide the same security guarantees as the power of 2 cyclotomic case.

One reason why these other cyclotomics are not as popular is that the speed of the Nunber Theoretic Transform in these other cyclotomics is not as computationally efficient.  Nevertheless as you point out there is a legitimate tradeoff between parameter sizes and computation.